# How to properly use leave/disconnect in Phoenix channels?

Tags: websocket, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm using Phoenix channels to stream data to a page with a tabbed interface. I'd like to only receive messages from a channel when the streaming tab is visible and to disconnect from the channel when the user has switched to another tab.

Currently I use something similar to the following code:

```
window.websockets_url = "ws://localhost:4000/socket";
window.channel_id = "some-channel-id"


onWindowLoad = ->
  initSocket()

onStreamShow = ->
  connectToSocket()

onStreamHide = ->
  disconnectFromSocket()


initSocket = ->
  window.socket = new (Phoenix.Socket)(window.websockets_url)

connectToSocket = ->
  window.socket.connect()
  channel = window.socket.channel("channel:#{window.channel_id}", {})
  channel.join()
  channel.on "event", (payload) ->
    doSomethingWithThePayload(payload)

disconnectFromSocket = ->
  window.socket.disconnect()
```

This works, but after calling `connectToSocket()` and `disconnectFromSocket()` multiple times I'm getting this message in the server logs:

> StreamChannel received join event with topic "channel:some-channel-id" but channel already joined

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Phoenix Socket API in Javascript is stateful. When you reconnect after a disconnect, it will reconnect to all the previous channels. You're then joining the channel a second time.

You can either re-initialize the socket (initSocket) or only join channels on the first connect.